# Sending messages to specific Smack domains after initial broadcast message

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm creating an instant messaging client using Smack 3.1.0 and Java. The problem I'm running in to has to do with sending messages to the user on a specific domain.

For example, I have two users, 1@gmail.com and 2@gmail.com. 1@gmail.com logs in to XMPP through my IM client. 2@gmail.com logs in to GChat through gmail.com AND a second time through pidgin. So now I have one instance of 1@gmail.com and 2 instances of 2@gmail.com.

The way gmail works, if 1@gmail.com sends a message to 2@gmail.com, the gmail and the pidgin client both get the initial message. But then if the gmail instance responds to the message, every message from then on only goes between 1@gmail.com and the gmail instance of 2@gmail.com.

I would like to mimic this behavior with my IM client. I would think the way to do it would be to set up a Chat, send the initial IM to all instances of the recipient. Then I'd set up a MessageListener to listen for a response. When I get the response, I'd have to create a new chat, specifying the 2@gmail.com/resource. But then I'd have to write the MessageListener twice. Any ideas? Here's some sample code that I'm using (the method `AddText()` simply appends the message to my conversation pane):

```
recipient = buddy;
setTitle("Instant Message - "+recipient);
chat = com.andreaslekas.pim.PIM.connection.getChatManager().createChat(recipient.getUser(), new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message msg) {
        //if(chat.getParticipant().indexOf('/')!=-1)
        addText(msg.getBody(), chat.getParticipant(), true);
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**
I wanted to supplement the answer below with actual code that I used to make this work:

```
chat = com.andreaslekas.pim.PIM.connection.getChatManager().createChat(recipient.getUser(), new MessageListener() {
    public void processMessage(Chat new_chat, Message msg) {
        if(msg.getFrom().replaceFirst("/.*", "").equals(recipient.getUser()))
        {
            if(buddy_resource==null || !msg.getFrom().replaceFirst(".*?/", "").equals(buddy_resource.getResource()))
            {
                buddy_resource = recipient.getResource(msg.getFrom().replaceFirst(".*?/", ""));
                chat = null;
                chat = com.andreaslekas.pim.PIM.connection.getChatManager().createChat(recipient.getUser()+"/"+buddy_resource.getResource(), new MessageListener(){
                    public void processMessage(Chat new_chat2, Message msg) {
                        addText(msg.getBody(), new_chat2.getParticipant(), true);
                    }
                });
            }
            addText(msg.getBody(), chat.getParticipant(), true);
        }
    }
});
```

To summarize, I send the first message to all resources of the recipient's address and wait for a response. When I get the response, I replace the current `Chat` object with a new one that specifies the individual resource that responded to the initial message. The code is a little messy with two different `MessageListener` objects that could probably be combined into a new class. But it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MessageListener why not always respond to the sender? I think you get it by calling something like msg.getSender() or getFrom() (I'm on mobile right now, cannot check)

Comment: msg.getFrom() is a String. To respond to the sender would require Chat newChat = connection.getChatManager().createChat(msg.getFrom(), new MessageListener(){});

Comment: Can you set that MessageListener to null? Since you already have a listener that will receive the response message.

Comment: Well, I can set that listener to null, but I'd be creating a new instance of Chat, so none of the incoming messages will be processed because the old listener gets destroyed.

Comment: If it gets destroyed, what's the issue with having a new listener? So what if the pidgin client responds after the gtalk has already started the new conversation?

Comment: I can try it. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 2):

So far I understood Message Carbon (XEP - 0280) will solve your problem.
If you enable carbon it will distribute messages to all logged resources of a user. In your case if 1@gmail.com send message to 2@gmail.com it will be distributed to all logged resources of 2@gmail.com.
Here's a code sample using smack,

```
CarbonManager cm = CarbonManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
cm.enableCarbons();
cm.sendCarbonsEnabled();
```

First make sure that your server is supported Message Carbon.
Then send message as usual.